# ERROR:requires both input and output filenames & Exiting before completion due to errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firebird

```
gbak -z
gbak:gbak version LI-V2.5.6.27020 Firebird 2.5
gbak: ERROR:requires both input and output filenames
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

Как исправить эту ошибку в Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: если эти строчки вас так смущают, найдите в исходниках место, где разработчики пропустили `exit`, добавьте, и пересоберите программу *gbak*. ну или хотя бы багрепорт пошлите: в версии 2.0.3 поведение было аналогичное.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно узнать по подробнее что это означает? Чтобы не думалось лишнего.

Comment: это означает ошибку в программе *gbak*, благодаря которой появляется упомянутое вами сообщение об «ошибке», которой, собственно, нет // хотите исправить ошибку? разберитесь в логике файла [`src/burp/burp.cpp`](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/src/burp/burp.cpp), где происходит обработка параметров (возможно, ещё какие-нибудь файлы потребуется править) и отправьте разработчикам pull-request.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin готов принять Ваш комментарий за ответ